# How to remotely devleop on an ESP2 using PyCharm Community Edition?

Tags: esp32

JetBrains PyCharm blog [announed](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/01/micropython-plugin-for-pycharm/) a MicroPython plug-in for PyCharm.

Alas, its [GitHub page](https://github.com/vlasovskikh/intellij-micropython) says

> The plugin supports these devices:
>
> ```
> BBC Micro:bit
> ESP8266
> PyBoard
> ```

Np ESP32 :-(

Can one remotely program and debug an ESP32 in Python, from Windows, preferably using PyCharm?

Comment: It looks like I can use CircuitPython and the Mu IDE, although there are not many boards supported   https://blog.adafruit.com/2019/01/26/circuitpython-is-supported-on-28-boards-and-2-more-that-are-shipping-but-not-in-releases-yet-for-a-total-of-30-different-boards-circuitpython-adafruit-arduino-bwshockley-electronicats-makerd/

Comment: However, I will probably just buy a JTAG probe and debug that wat